# Get all points within some distance by the path

Tags: mysql, path, coordinates, point

I have multiple points with coordinates which represent the path on a map. Then I have multiple points, which represent for example restaurants. I'd like to get all the restaurants, which are near my path, like to 1 km. One of the solutions is that for each point I'll search for the restaurant in the circle of 1 km from that point in the MySQL database, but I'd like to know some other option.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a polygon from the path, that represents the area of interest, and than test the points for intersection.

Comment: How can I make a polygon from it?

Answer (score 0):

You could further put lines between each pair of adjacent points on the path, and then compute the shortest distance from the lines to each point representing a restaurant. Then you just filter out the restaurants with a distance greater than 1km.

For distance computation between line and point have a look on this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)